# Specify the maximum number of items in a List<T>?

Tags: c#

How can I set the maximum number of items of my list?

I tried to set it to 2, but the code didn't break, and I got the 4 items added.

```
List<string> listeTraitements = new List<string>(2);
listeTraitements.Add("ee");
listeTraitements.Add("ee");
listeTraitements.Add("ee");
listeTraitements.Add("ee");
```

Comment: The constructor parameter that takes an `int` on a `List`, is not the maximum, its just the starting capacity. If you want to limit then use an array I guess

Comment: `List<T>` doesn't support setting an upper limit. You're using [this constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_Collections_Generic_List_1__ctor_System_Int32_) which states the integer value is: _"The number of elements that the new list can initially store."_

Comment: Why do you want to set a capacity limit on a list? This sounds like an https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: Also, what should happen if you reach said limit?

Comment: The entiry purpose of a list compared to an array is, that you can dynamically add items. Why do you want to limit your list to a specific size? That contradicts that point completely.

Comment: Why don't you just define an Array?

Comment: What is the expected behavior? Do you want third `Add` call to throw exception? Or do you want the new value to be added, but the total number of items should no exceed given maximum? Circular buffer?

Answer (score 2):

The parameter of this constructor is for setting the **initial capacity** of the list:

> public List (int capacity);

Your only alternative to limit the number of elements to add would be to use an array instead:

```
    var strings = new string[2]
    {
        "ee",
        "ee"
    };
```

Note that specifying the number of elements in the array is optional when you use the initializer syntax like I did.